# Downloading the contents of a web directory?

Tags: ftp, webserver

If I have `example.com/dir` and `dir` is basically a folder in the `example.com` server, how can I download the contents of the folder to my hard drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a webserver and you download over the net? Then (with shell access) you might try:

```
$ wget --wait 2 -rkc --no-parent http://example.com/dir
```

Works with ftp, too.

Comment: wget is also [available](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for Windows